# Javascript Verbs Detection

Tags: javascript, nlp

I've the following problem. I need to find **verbs** in a string using `JavaScript`.
I would like to know, if there is something like (JAWS), the Java API for `Wordnet`, but for JavaScript.

More specifically, i'm searching for some kind of RESTful webservice able to return the list of verbs in a text or webpage.

If you know something useful, please don't hesitate to post your answers.

Comment: You could find all the words ending in "ing" or have "to " before them, plus common ones like "are" and "is"

Comment: Problem is that I need all verbs, comprising irregular verbs etc.. More than an algorithm, i need a database :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [Natural Language Processing APIs](http://text-processing.com/demo/). They seem to have an [API](http://text-processing.com/docs/). There is even a [service](http://www.mashape.com/apis/Text-Processing) for larger amounts of requests (has a free plan as well).

It is based on simple POST requests and returns JSON, so it would be easy to use in JavaScript.